# How to get rid of half a can of durable water repellent spray (similar to 3M Scotchgard)

Tags: waste, reuse, pollution, toxic-chemicals, pfas

(Cross-posted, together with additional questions, to [a post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Anticonsumption/comments/163j8pl/how_to_get_rid_of_half_a_can_of_durable_water/) on the /r/Anticonsumption sub-Reddit.)

I have an 8 ounce (~200 g) can of Foot Locker ultra fabric & leather protector spray.  I guess this is a [durable water repellent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durable_water_repellent) chemical concoction, similar to 3M Scotchgard.  I think the can may still be half full, or more.  I now know that these kinds of products often contain PFAS "forever chemicals", and are not very good for the environment.  Therefore, I think it might not be a good idea for me to use up the rest of the contents of the can.

What's the most sustainable way for me to get rid of what's left?

- A.) Should I put it out in a box at the curb labelled "Free", and let someone else take it? They may spray it on garments which eventually end up in landfill. Later on, landfill leachate can contaminate groundwater. [(Source.)](https://chemsec.org/nobody-really-knows-what-happens-to-pfas-when-we-throw-our-old-products-away-2/#:%7E:text=As%20of%20today,contaminate%20the%20groundwater.)
- B.) Should I try to sell it for US$1 on a local classifieds website?
- C.) Should I offer it to the staff at a local outdoors store, who otherwise might buy their own can?
- D.) Should I take it to a hazardous waste drop-off point here in Toronto, and ask them to send it for incineration? Unfortunately, normal hazardous waste incineration (perhaps [2200 °F](https://www.frtr.gov/matrix2/section4/4-23.html#:%7E:text=1%2C200%20%C2%B0C%20(1%2C600%2D-,2%2C200%20%C2%B0F,-%29%2C%20are%20used%20to)) may not be [hot enough](https://msutoday.msu.edu/news/2022/ask-the-expert-how-to-destoy-pfas?collection=79022467-cc5d-4b0d-9d69-8f773df52178#:%7E:text=2%2C730%20degrees%20Fahrenheit) to destroy PFAS.
- E.) Should I keep the product, and re-spray my winter coat (which is no longer water-repellent)?
- F.) Should I do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give more than my opinion to this but from your options I would choose "C". If you know of people that are already using the product that would be the best option.

My rationale:

- A: Could easily just end up in general waste
- D: If you know of people that already use the product then you are destroying this one for no reason.
- E: It seems you have already decided that you no longer want to use it

"B" would be a good option depending where you live (how far do people have to travel to you).

Beyond an opinion [reducereuserecycle.co.uk](https://www.reducereuserecycle.co.uk/greenarticles/what_does_reduce_reuse_recycle_mean.php) offers these options under reuse which are similar to your proposals:

> Sell the item, for example by advertising it on one of the many websites such as eBay, on Facebook groups or via local newspapers. If it is an antique or collectable item you may be able to sell it to a local antiques shop.

> Give it to a friend that needs the item.

> Donate it to a charity shop (thrift store) where it can be sold to raise money for a good cause.

> Give it to somebody who is looking for something, via websites such as Freecycle or Freegle.

> Hold a yard sale or get a pitch at a car boot sale.